# Asp.Net MVC does not hide the parameter name in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to hide the parameters in URL. But what I am getting is like

```
http://localhost:62025/Forum/HomePage/GetReviews?itemid=1&itemname=Redmi-Note-5
```

My Routing is

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ItemReviews",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{itemid}/{itemname}",
               defaults: new { controller = "HomePage", action = "GetReviews", itemid = "", itemname = "" }
           );
```

and my Action method is

```
public ActionResult GetReviews(string itemid, string itemname)
{
 return View();
}
```

And my view is

```
<a class="text-primary" href="@Url.Action("GetReviews", "HomePage", new { itemid = review.ItemId.ToString(), itemname = review.ItemName.Replace(" ", "-")})"> @review.ItemName </a>
```

I would like to get my URL like

```
http://localhost:62025/Forum/HomePage/GetReviews/1/Redmi-Note-5
```

Comment: As I see you need attribute routing. Start here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: @ZorgoZ Excellent! It is working fine now. Thanks much for your instant help.